# find the largest sum that can be achieved by a procedure

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, induction, contest-math

> Given real numbers $x_1\leq x_2\leq \cdots x_n, n>2$, perform the following procedure:

1. Arrange the numbers in a circle.
2. Delete one of the numbers.
3. If just two numbers are left, take their sum. Otherwise replace each number by the sum of it and the number on its right. Go to step 2.

> Show that the largest sum that can be achieved by this procedure is $\sum_{k=2}^n {n-2\choose \lfloor k/2\rfloor - 1} x_k.$

I can show how the largest sum can be achieved by induction, but I'm not sure how to show it's the largest possible. To prove that the sum can indeed be achieved, we use induction on $n$, with the base case $n=3$ being obvious (we can just delete $x_1$). consider the numbers $x_2,x_4,x_6,\cdots, x_{n + 1}, \cdots x_3,x_1$ arranged in a circle (clockwise say, where $n'$ is the largest odd number that's at most $n+1$ and $n''$ is the largest even number that's at most $n+1$). Delete $x_1$ to get the numbers $y_1,\cdots, y_n, y_1 = x_2 + x_3, y_n = x_n + x_{n+1}, y_i = x_i + x_{i+2}$ for $1 < i < n$. Applying induction to the $y_i$'s now gives that the sum $\sum_{k=2}^n {n-2\choose \lfloor k/2\rfloor - 1} y_k$ can be achieved. So it suffices to show that $\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} {n-1\choose \lfloor k/2\rfloor - 1} x_k = \sum_{k=2}^n {n-2\choose \lfloor k/2\rfloor - 1} y_k,$ and one can verify this by using identities like Pascal's identity. Indeed, we have the following:

$\begin{align} \sum_{k=2}^n {n-2\choose \lfloor k/2\rfloor - 1}y_k &= x_2 + x_3 + \sum_{k=4}^{n-1} ({n-2\choose \lfloor k/2\rfloor - 1} + {n-2\choose \lfloor k/2\rfloor - 2})x_k \\
&+ ({n-2\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor - 1} + {n-2\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor - 2}) x_n + ({n-2\choose \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor - 1} + {n-2\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor - 1})x_{n+1}\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{n}{n-1\choose \lfloor k/2\rfloor - 1} x_k + ({n-2\choose \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor - 1} + {n-2\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor - 1})x_{n+1},\end{align}$

and now we can split into cases based on the parity of n. In case 1, $n=2k+1$ for some k, so the coefficient of $x_{n+1}$ is ${2k-1\choose k-1} + {2k-1\choose k-1} = {2k\choose k} = {n-1\choose \lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor - 1}$. If $n=2k$ is even, the coefficient is ${2k-2\choose k-2} + {2k-2\choose k-1} = {2k-1\choose k - 1} = {n-1\choose \lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor - 1}$.